# Replace pandas column with list values from another panadas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to modify the  `main_df` dataframe by replacing its **Product** list values with corresponding Model list values from the  `mapping_df`, but only if they are found in the lookup list  `to_replace_values`.

For example, the first **Product** value at index 0 in the  `main_df` is replaced with all corresponding **Model** values from the  `mapping_df`, but this is only applicable if the **Product** value is found in the lookup list  `to_replace_values`.

```
 main_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'Product': {
        0: "['Passenger Cars']",
        1: "['New Cars', 'Mercedes-Maybach']",
        2: "['New Cars', 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class']",
        3: "['New Cars', 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class', 'Mercedes-AMG CLA Coupe']"
    }
})

to_replace_values = [
    'Passenger Cars',
    'Mercedes-Benz Vans',
    'New Cars',
    'New Vans',
    'Mercedes-Maybach',
    'Mercedes-Benz',
    'Mercedes-AMG',
    'EQ Technology'
]

mapping_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': {
        0: 'New Cars',
        1: 'New Cars',
        2: 'Passenger Cars',
        3: 'Passenger Cars',
        4: 'Mercedes-Maybach',
        5: 'Mercedes-Maybach'
    },
    'Model': {
        0: 'Mercedes-Benz GLA',
        1: 'Mercedes-Benz GLB',
        2: 'Mercedes-Benz GLE',
        3: 'Mercedes-Benz GLS',
        4: 'Mercedes-Maybach GLS',
        5: 'Mercedes-Maybach S-Class'
}})

expected_outputs = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
    'Product': {
        0: "['Mercedes-Benz GLE', 'Mercedes-Benz GLS']",
        1: "['Mercedes-Benz GLA', 'Mercedes-Benz GLB', 'Mercedes-Maybach GLS', 'Mercedes-Maybach S-Class']",
        2: "['Mercedes-Benz GLA', 'Mercedes-Benz GLB', 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class']",
        3: "['Mercedes-Benz GLA', 'Mercedes-Benz GLB', 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class', 'Mercedes-AMG CLA Coupe']"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if need working with lists - first filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and aggregate lists, then in list comprehension mapping by `dict.get`:

```
import ast

s = (mapping_df[mapping_df['Product'].isin(to_replace_values)]
                                     .groupby('Product')['Model']
                                     .agg(list))
print (s)
Product
Mercedes-Maybach    [Mercedes-Maybach GLS, Mercedes-Maybach S-Class]
New Cars                      [Mercedes-Benz GLA, Mercedes-Benz GLB]
Passenger Cars                [Mercedes-Benz GLE, Mercedes-Benz GLS]
Name: Model, dtype: object

out = main_df.assign(Product = [[z for y in ast.literal_eval(x) 
                                   for z in s.get(y,[y])]  for x in main_df['Product']])
print (out)
                                             Product
0             [Mercedes-Benz GLE, Mercedes-Benz GLS]
1  [Mercedes-Benz GLA, Mercedes-Benz GLB, Mercede...
2  [Mercedes-Benz GLA, Mercedes-Benz GLB, Mercede...
3  [Mercedes-Benz GLA, Mercedes-Benz GLB, Mercede...
```

Another similar idea, if lists are in real data omit converting strings to lists by `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

main_df['Product'] = main_df['Product'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

s = (mapping_df[mapping_df['Product'].isin(to_replace_values)]
                                     .groupby('Product')['Model']
                                     .agg(list))
    
out = main_df.assign(Product = [[z for y in x for z in s.get(y,[y])] 
                                   for x in main_df['Product']])
print (out)
                                             Product
0             [Mercedes-Benz GLE, Mercedes-Benz GLS]
1  [Mercedes-Benz GLA, Mercedes-Benz GLB, Mercede...
2  [Mercedes-Benz GLA, Mercedes-Benz GLB, Mercede...
3  [Mercedes-Benz GLA, Mercedes-Benz GLB, Mercede...
```

Alternative with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
out = main_df.assign(Product = main_df['Product']
                               .apply(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in s.get(y,[y])]))
```

EDIT:

For testing rows which failed converting to lists is possible use:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'Product': {
        0: ['Passenger Cars'],
        1: "['New Cars', 'Mercedes-Maybach']",
        2: "['New Cars', 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class']",
        3: "['New Cars', 'Mercedes-Benz C-Class', 'Mercedes-AMG CLA Coupe']"
    }
})

def test(x):
    try:
         ast.literal_eval(x)
         return False
    except ValueError:
         return True

s = main_df.loc[main_df['Product'].apply(test),'Product'].to_list()
print (s)
[['Passenger Cars']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, while running the script I got this error "ValueError: malformed node or string: ['Passenger Cars']", can you please check this

Comment: @IbrahimAyoup - this errro is in `main_df['Product'] = main_df['Product'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ?

Comment: I encountered the same error in both ideas when running with the full dataset. The errors are the same from both ideas`ValueError: malformed node or string: ['Mercedes-AMG GLE 53 Coupe']`, and the case as per the error is from `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @IbrahimAyoup - added solution for test problematic strings - what return `print (s)` in your real data?

Comment: Now its resolved thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

If you make examples with simpler words, it will be much easier to solve problems and understand code.

use replace by mapper(`m`) with regex

```
m = mapping_df[mapping_df['Product'].isin(to_replace_values)].groupby('Product')['Model'].agg("', '".join)
out = main_df.replace(m, regex=True)
```

out:

```
Product
0   ['Mercedes-Benz GLE', 'Mercedes-Benz GLS']
1   ['Mercedes-Benz GLA', 'Mercedes-Benz GLB', 'Me...
2   ['Mercedes-Benz GLA', 'Mercedes-Benz GLB', 'Me...
3   ['Mercedes-Benz GLA', 'Mercedes-Benz GLB', 'Me...
```

checking result

```
out.equals(expected_outputs)
```

```
True
```